# How can I make Regular expression for decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I make Regular expression for decimal(9,6) ?
wanna validate in Rails program.
please help me.

Comment: We'd like to help as long as we know you have put some efforts on solving your own problem by showing them.

Comment: Please add more details, with code. Do you mean your database's `DECIMAL` format? Otherwise, the answer is just `/\A\d{,9}\.\d{,6}\z/`, which might not be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

If you want numbers like 1.2 and 1 to be allowed

```
[\d]{1,9}\.?[\d]{0,6}
```

Or if you want at least one decimal place then you can use:

```
[\d]{1,9}\.[\d]{1,6}
```

Or if you want exactly 9 digits before decimal and 6 digits after decimal, then you can use:

```
[\d]{9}\.[\d]{6}
```

Comment: If it's not clear from OP what they are looking for, please ask them.

Comment: @revo OP is asking for a regex to match decimal number with upto 9 digits on left side and upto 6 digits as decimal places. Atleast this is what I got from the requirement

Comment: Going with three different solutions means OP wasn't clear enough about requirements. BTW `decimal(9,6)` does probably mean 9 digits at most with 6 digits in fractional part: `^\d{1,3}\.\d{6}$`

Comment: @revo Thanks for sharing, Yes you are right, let OP come back and confirm exact requirement.

Comment: thank you so much !  123.456789 is okay.and 12.234567 is also okay!

Comment: @yoyo Great! Plese accept it as answer in that case

Comment: 32.1234000 is okay.also 139.711111 is okay. which case is the best way to match these condithions?

Comment: @yoyo I have already shared on what requirement to you which case, now that depends on you :)

Comment: @yoyo is `999999999.999999` okay?